# SwiftUI cannot read data of Document using .fileImporter - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-fileimporter

Trying to read data of document using following code block

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showDocPicker, allowedContentTypes: [SupportDocTypes], onCompletion: { result in
    do {
        let fileURL = try result.get()
        let docData  = try Data(contentsOf:fileURL) // <-error on this line
    } catch {
        print ("error reading")
        print (error.localizedDescription)
    }
})
```

and it gives the following error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “a.txt” couldn’t be
> opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CCB51769-028A-4C15-A2C2-3A263791BA08/Documents/a.txt,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x283e6a4f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
> "Operation not permitted"}}

This error occurred only on physical device.
Xcode 13.2.1
Tested on iOS 15.2 | 14.8

Answer (score 5):

Use `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showDocPicker, allowedContentTypes: [SupportDocTypes], onCompletion: { result in
        do {
            let fileURL = try result.get()
            if fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                let docData  = try Data(contentsOf:fileURL) 
                //other codes
            }
            
        } catch {
            print ("error reading")
            print (error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso)